# how to access prviate members of an instance in c++,

Tags: c++

I get error when tring to access a private member of a class. My aim was to create a class, make an object and then access what was inputted into it.

So I created a User1.hpp file for my declarations.

```
class user1 {

private:
    string username1;
    string email;
    string mobile;
    
public:
    user1(string Myfirstname , string emailaddress , string mobile); //constructor

};
```

In my User1.cpp file, I implemented the class

```
user1::user1(string Myfirstname , string emailaddress , string mobile)
{
    user1::username1 = Myfirstname;
    user1::email = emailaddress;
    
}
```

then in main.cpp I created the first object and inputted some random data.

```
user1 firstman {"John" , "john1@email.com" , "011000000"};
```

Now when I want to see what 'firstman's email was in main.cpp, I tried this:

```
cout<<"Created "<< firstman.username1 <<" !"<<endl;
```

Which gives me the error of a private member. What is the best approach to accessing that data?

Comment: This is the idea of private members, they should be not accessed from outside the class.

Comment: If you want to be able to access them, don't make them private?

Comment: In your case you may want to define public getters for your private fields, such as `string getEmail() { return this->email; }`

Comment: Why is `username1` private? You could make it `const` instead.

Comment: The question is what did you think the purpose of private was? It's working exactly as it is supposed to.

Comment: please start reading literaly any book on C++ on page 1.

Comment: I thought it might of been a secure way of accessing it. But thanks for clearly that up.

Comment: @Reinhold I don't know any book that mentions `private` in the preface ;)

Answer (score 1):

Private members are meant to be inaccessible from outside the class. You could make `username1` public and const:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class user1 {
    
public:
    const std::string username1;
    user1(std::string Myfirstname, std::string emailaddress, std::string); //constructor

private:
    std::string email;
    std::string mobile;

};

user1::user1(std::string Myfirstname, std::string emailaddress, std::string): username1(Myfirstname), email(emailaddress) {}

int main() {
    user1 firstman {"John" , "john1@email.com" , "011000000"};
    
    std::cout << "Created " << firstman.username1 << " !\n";
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks Thomas for clarify the private/public and using const

Comment: Actually, providing a getter function might be the better solution (see comment by @Yang Hanlin above). If you are having `const` members in a class, using instances of these classes e.g., in containers (`std::vector`, `std::map`, ...) can be rather cumbersome.

Comment: @dasmy _"Actually, providing a getter function might be the better solution"_ That's an opinion. IMHO getters should be avoided if not necessary. In some companies it already became an anti pattern because it often pollutes classes, especially when there are pairs of trivial getters and setters.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: In principle, I agree that getters can be really annoying boilerplate code and especially for simple data structures, I personally prefer public members. Being a bit old-fashioned, I am using `struct` instead of `class` these cases. I do think, however, that this is not a good recommendation for a programming beginner, as this quickly can void encapsulation.

Comment: @dasmy https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-const https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rh-get